# Ubuntu stucks on splash screen while installing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my ASUS X553M alongside Windows 8. I created a bootable USB using Rufus. But when I tried to install Ubuntu, it got stuck on splash screen. I tried `nomodset` and disabled fast startup.

I had previously installed Ubuntu on my machine but the partition of Ubuntu was accidentally deleted using AOMEI Partition Assistant.

I tried everything that I could. I had Ubuntu 16.04 installed, which is also what I am now now trying to install. The disk has no defects. I have checked it twice and there were no errors.

What might be going wrong during installation?

Comment: Keep in mind that how it boots it's how it installs. You want UEFI mode, not Legacy, due to the factory installed Windows 8. And with Rufus you also need to explicitly select the GPT/UEFI setting. `nomodeset` isn't applicable unless you have a very new (or weird) Nvidia graphics not supported by the open source driver.

Comment: my windows is installed in legacy mode so so i cannot in uefi right although it don't matter because i tried both but still no work

Comment: The Asus X553M comes with Windows 8 (UEFI). Have you reinstalled and if so, why legacy?

Comment: actually accidentally my system went wrong with my system and in tension i installed it using windows 8 dvd in legacy mode

Comment: so is there any way i can install ubuntu on my system because in splash screen it is stuck at saying keyboard or something and it says ntfs is unsafe in some upper lines

Comment: Back to my first comment, how it boots is how it installs. Nothing else to add. I suggest you learn about OSes in general and UEFI and everything that entails before trying again.

Comment: okay but i installed it before but why its not working now is it because i deleted ubuntu partition when i last installed it

Comment: @KaranRustagi You mentioned "nomodset." Had you typed `nomodset` (without the first `e`) or `nomodeset` (which is correct)? I very much doubt this is the key to solving your problem, but if you think nomodeset might help and you had spelled it wrong when you gave it to the kernel as a boot option, then you might want to try again with `nomodeset` and report back. ...Regarding the splash screen, is that the splash screen that shows your computer manufacturer's logo? Or is it an Ubuntu splash screen? If the latter, what happens when you press Escape? (I suggest editing your post with this info.)

Comment: actually i saw somewhere nomodeset can help i tried it both ways by highlighting try ubuntu without installing and adding command at the end of the linux line and by turning it on by hitting f6  during installation